# how to use jquery .append() in a JS FOR loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

ok so i have this function

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#chat').val(data);
    for (var i = 0, i < data.length, i++) {
        $.append("#ID: " + "#Mesaage");
    }
}
```

in which data is variable that holds a JSON array which is displayed like this:

`{ID:  Message}`

How can I give it a format so it will simply print "ID: Message" without the curly brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Object.keys` here:

```
success: function (data) {
    var key = Object.keys(data)
    $('#chat').val(key +":"+ data[key]);
},
```

A sample test is below:

```js
var data = {"Id":"Message"};
var key = Object.keys(data);
$(document.body).append(key +":"+ data[key]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is a JSON element here, it acts like a normal object or class instance, you can access the value of `ID` by simply calling `data.ID`.

E.g.

```
$.append ("ID: " + data.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this (not sure what you mean by the curly brackets...)? Regardless, you need to amend the code for your loop first because you'll get a syntax error:

```
success: function (data) {

    // cache your DOM element
    $chat = $('#chat');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $chat.append('ID: ' + data[i].Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`$.append` is invalid without a selector. You need to tell jQuery where you are placing the html

```
$(selector).append("#ID: " + "#Mesaage");
```

Also use proper `for` syntax with `;` separators not `,`

Also you can't do `$('#chat').val(data)` since data is an array